# What exactly is akka.dispatch.Dispatcher$$anon$1?

Tags: java, scala, akka

I was analyzing a Java heap dump when one of our application servers ran out of memory. I was using Eclipse Memory Analyzer. It reported the following.

> One instance of "akka.dispatch.Dispatcher$$anon$1" loaded by
>   "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xc5602128" occupies 675,632,768
>   (73.50%) bytes.

1. What do the $$anon and $1 in the class name mean?
2. What exactly is the object that's taking 73.5% of heap space? What could be the cause?

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have exactly same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First anonymous class. Looking at source code I guess it is the Mailbox: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/Dispatcher.scala#L89 (Scala objects created with traits are compiled to anonymous classes)
2. The tool you are using should be able to tell which objects are directly hold/referenced by Mailbox and are actually using memory. Probably actors are simply not processing messages fast enough.